# 2 classes with a parameter in its constructor of the other class

Tags: java

Lets say I have class A and class B. Their constructor looks like this:

```
 public A(B b) {this.b = b;}

 public B(A a) {this.a = a;}
```

Both of them have an instance of the other class as an instance variable.

Is it possible to create instances of those classes without an instancevariable being null?
I want an instance of class A and an instance of class B. The instance of class A should add the instance of class B as its instance variable and and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

One of the classes, let's choose `A`, will need a method

```
public void setB(B b) {
    this.b = b;
}
```

that can be called after `A` and `B` objects are instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

Two classes are tightly coupled. If each class instance require the other one to initialize, then the class design need to be revised from the beginning. Instead, to archive the goal of one instance has the other, using `setter` would help in this case

```
class A {
    private B b;
    public A(B b) { this.b = b; }
}

class B {
    private A a;
    void setA(A a) { this.a = a; }
}
B b = new B();
A a = new A(b);
b.setA(a);
```

Comment: Isn't it the solution which question's author wants to avoid?